# groupBy with eloquent relationship in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to fetch data for my invoice page wherein I used many appended rows against single invoice number. I fetched data but the problem is I can not show the appended rows in invoice view page. What should be written the query to get the expected result, Would someone help me, please?
My database table is - [image: order_proforma_invoices]

And I am expecting like below what I did during crate-
[image: view page]

In my controller, I tried something like this-

```
public function orderProformaInvoiceDetails($poi)
{

    $orderProformaInvoiceDetails = OrderProformaInvoice::where('opi_id', $poi)
                                        ->with('buyer', 'buyerJobs', 'buyerOrders')
                                        ->groupBy('invoice_no')
                                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                                        ->get();

    return view('admin.marchendaising.order-proforma-invoices.details', compact('orderProformaInvoiceDetails'));
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error? or what problem you have with the method you have tried?

Comment: I want to show many `Style Name` `Description` `Fabrics` `Quantity` `Unit Price` `Total Price` for an invoice as I did during create the invoice.

Comment: Why are you using `groupBy()`? Should your view have one row per `invoice_no`?

Comment: I have many rows per `invoice_no` that's why I need `groupBy()` and I want to show 'unit_price` , `quantity` , `total_price` as row for every `invoice_no`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group the query result:

```
OrderProformaInvoice::where('opi_id', $poi)
    ->with('buyer', 'buyerJobs', 'buyerOrders')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('invoice_no');

@foreach($orderProformaInvoiceDetails as $invoice_no => $details)
    @foreach($details as $detail)
        {{ $detail->quantity }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```